# What is the SE standpoint about questions with answers that are links to off-site resources?

Tags: support, questions

What is the Stack Exchange standpoint about questions with answers that are links to off-site resources? Can single sites decide about those type of questions?

On the network meta site, those kind of questions, including the ones asking for lists, are always described as not welcome. The reason I normally read is that in such questions, users would just vote the answers not basing on their correctness, but something more subjective, or just to mean (in the case of questions asking for off-site resources) *I use it too*.
Some sites, like Stack Overflow, even have a closing reason for such questions, that in the case of Stack Overflow is the following one:

> Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Since voting is a feature for all the sites in the Stack Exchange network, does Stack Exchange have a standpoint about those questions? Can the single sites decide about those questions? If the answer is *yes*, what is the margin of those decisions?

Comment: [softwarerecs.SE] is also a Stack Exchange site, so the quoted [SO] rule cannot apply to the whole network.

Comment: In fact, I am not saying that rule is valid for every Stack Exchange site. I am asking how much autonomy do new Stack Exchange sites have for those type of questions.